# Generate boxplots for multiple variables in ggplot2 without factoring

Tags: r, ggplot2

EDIT: Added the boxplot generated with standard boxplot() function.

Given the iris dataste, the following code:

```
boxplot(iris[,])
```

Creates a boxplot with five boxes, one for each variable, without splitting them into categories such as, for instance, species. While this is simple enough, I have been unable to do the same in ggplot2.

[image: Boxplot generated with standard function.]

My question, then, is simple: how can I achieve this?

Comment: Questions about how to use R code are generally off topic here. This may be on topic on [SO], if you wait, we can try to migrate it there.

Comment: I apologize deeply! A migration would be fantastic!

Comment: You needn't apologize, I'm just letting you know for future reference. If you want to speed up the migration, you can flag your Q & ask the moderators to migrate it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Species` is a factor with three levels (`setosa`, `versicolor` and `virginica`). I think it doesn't make sense if you plot it with the other variables.

It makes more sense if you want to plot all other 4 variables (`Sepal.Length`, `Sepal.Width`,  `Petal.Length`, and `Petal.Width`) in one plot as below

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)
iris %>% dplyr::select(Species, everything()) %>% tidyr::gather("id", "value",2:5) %>% 
  ggplot(., aes(x = id, y = value))+geom_boxplot()
```

[image]

If you want to plot all 5 variables in the same plot, you need to convert `species` to be numeric

```
iris %>% dplyr::mutate(Species = as.numeric(Species)) %>% tidyr::gather("id", "value",1:5) %>% 
  ggplot(., aes(x = id, y = value))+geom_boxplot()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I agree. Unfortunately, I need to plot such a boxplot because I was ordered to. It's not up to me.

Comment: @DanksC.

Please, check the updated answer