# How to make multiple box plot using R

Tags: r, ggplot2, boxplot

This is the headt of my data set

```
ï..age    sex cp trestbps chol fbs restecg thalach exang oldpeak slope ca thal
1     63   male  3      145  233   1       0     150     0     2.3     0  0    1
2     37   male  2      130  250   0       1     187     0     3.5     0  0    2
3     41 female  1      130  204   0       0     172     0     1.4     2  0    2
4     56   male  1      120  236   0       1     178     0     0.8     2  0    2
5     57 female  0      120  354   0       1     163     1     0.6     2  0    2
6     57   male  0      140  192   0       1     148     0     0.4     1  0    1
  target
1    yes
2    yes
3    yes
4    yes
5    yes
```

the depended variable is the target an I want to plot a multiple box plot  of the numeric variables only (age, trestbps, thalach...) and I want to fill it with the depended variable (target), each of this variable must filled with the depended variable. How to do that?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Generate boxplots for multiple variables in ggplot2 without factoring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42990342/generate-boxplots-for-multiple-variables-in-ggplot2-without-factoring)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following code

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>% 
  mutate_if(is.numeric,as.character, is.factor, as.character) %>% 
  pivot_longer(-target) %>%
  filter(!((name == "sex"))) %>% 
  mutate(value = as.numeric(value)) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = target, y = value)) +
  geom_boxplot() +
  facet_wrap(name~., scales = "free")
```

[image]

Data

```
df <- read.table(text = "age    sex cp  trestbps    chol    fbs restecg thalach exang   oldpeak slope   ca  thal    target
63  male    3   145 233 1   0   150 0   2.3 0   0   1   yes
37  male    2   130 250 0   1   187 0   3.5 0   0   2   yes
41  female  1   130 204 0   0   172 0   1.4 2   0   2   yes
56  male    1   120 236 0   1   178 0   0.8 2   0   2   yes
57  female  0   120 354 0   1   163 1   0.6 2   0   2   yes
57  male    0   140 192 0   1   148 0   0.4 1   0   1   yes", header =T)
```